# Neural net termination rule

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I want to build my first neural net for recognazing hand-written digits in python, but I cant find a good, simple termination rule?

What I mean by "termination rule" is when to stop updating my weights and biases, or how to know I've reached a lcal min.

Let me be clear. I’m not looking for the best performing-most advanced-most sophisticated rule. On the contrary, I want the simplest, easiest to implement, good to get started rule that will just get the job **reasonably** done.

If there is any more information requierd for you to answer, please do tell and I'll add it here.

Comment: Often it's simply limited by a number of training epochs. You never know for sure you've reached the min, but can be pretty much confident looking at the loss chart

Comment: Have a look at [Keras early stopping](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping)

Comment: thank you for your answers. @Maxim, can you please further explain how to use the loss chart to determain the right number f training epochs?

Comment: @desertnaut, I've taken a look at it, and it dosent seem to inclulde the mathemathical background on how is it working, so I'm not sure how to implement it in the neural  net i'm building from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the question is somewhat too broad, I'll try to provide you with general guidance.

Neural network training is the process of optimization of high-dimensional (almost always) non-convex loss function. As a result, it's very rare to have a formal proof about its global or local minima or convergence speed. There're mere *observations* that, for instance, all local minima are approximately the same in terms of test accuracy (loss), which makes the learning process easier as finding the global minimum is no longer mandatory.

The "termination rule" you're asking about is in the same category: it's a general rule that *seems* to be working in most cases. When you're doing cross-validation, you should stop training when the validation accuracy (loss) stops improving and goes flat or gets worse for some period of time. The result model can be reasonably selected as the best over the whole training process. One can also apply early-stopping (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/231061/130598) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34603987/712995)), to save training time and still avoid overfitting. Essentially, in practice, the researches let the network train as long as the time limit allows and increase the number of epochs only if the accuracy (loss) still does not *look* flat, which is rare.

For instance, on the chart below, 10 epochs is too early to stop, because there's a lot of potential for improvement. It's still unclear after 15 epochs. It's ok to stop after 20 epochs, if there's lack of time, but I'd let it run until epoch 25 to be sure. At this point, the training score is almost 1.0, validation score is flat, i.e., no sign it could improve further.

[image: accuracy-chart]